# How do I make use of an already existing, external servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets

We have a form with 2 input fields.

These allow a user to type in destinations to plan a flight.

We want to use an external servlet that allows us to use autocompletion on the fields
(e.g. type "LO" and it gets the matches for that - London Heathrow would be at the top)

The servlet can be found at a URL like this: http://www.companyname.com/servlet/ac.json?n=12&q=LO

with "n" being the amount of results it should return, and "q" being the query.

How do I call that servlet from my HTML form, everytime the input field changes?

The servlet is on a different domain than my page, and I have absolutely no other access than calling it with the URL I posted.

The response from the servlet will always be a JSON string like this:

```
[{"type":"airport","city":"Cape Town","airport":"International","iata":"CPT","country":"South Africa","locationId":"airport_CPT"},
{"type":"city","city":"Chicago, IL","airport":"All Airports","iata":"CHI","country":"United States","locationId":"US_city_CHI"},
{"type":"airport","city":"Victoria","airport":"CA","iata":"YYJ","country":"Canada","locationId":"airport_YYJ"}]
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. What does your servlet return as a result? Will the servlet and the page calling it be on the same domain (cross domain problems)? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
How do I call that servlet from my HTML form, everytime the input field changes?
```

I strongly belive ,you need **AJAX** for this.If you use a normal servlet and use a `form` to `submit`  each time the page will reload.

And coming to same servlet part,

You can specify the method names in **AJAX request**

Comment: but that won't work so easily if the servlet is indeed an external servlet, in another domain. You'd need a proxy.

Comment: @eis: he doesn't necessarily need a proxy. He can adjust his web server to allow cross domain ajax from a given domain. Or even use JSONP, if he is able to modify the existing servlet (what we don't know because the question does not contain enough information).

Comment: @mael by "external" I'm assuming it is out of his control. If he has access to that servlet or domain, then yes, you are correct.

Comment: @eis: yes you're right, that's a possibility. As he uses "mycompanyname.com" as the domain for the "external" servlet, I thought that it **could** be a servlet hosted by his company.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **JSP page** in place of Servlet. You can call it very easily and it will complete your purpose also.  Otherwise **AJAX** is best for this type of problem.